# SQL Getting missing expression when using regexp_substr

Tags: oracle, plsql

my proc is:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE SP_TBL_COMPARE_TEST3(
    SRC_COLS     IN VARCHAR2,
    TGT_COLS     IN VARCHAR2)
IS
  CNT1     NUMBER(5);
  SQL_TEXT2 VARCHAR(4000);

BEGIN
  SQL_TEXT2:= 'select count(*) from (select regexp_substr('||src_cols||','||'[^,]+'||', +1, level) from dual connect by regexp_substr('||src_cols||','||'[^,]+'||', +1, level) is not null )'; 
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SQL_TEXT2 into CNT4;
END
```

I am trying to get the input for the src cols and separating to count them but i am getting invalid identifier error. but the columns are available in the input and it is accurate

> Connecting to the database sp_test. ORA-00936: missing expression
>   ORA-06512: at "SP_TEST.SP_TBL_COMPARE_TEST3", line 19 ORA-06512: at
>   line 13 Process exited. Disconnecting from the database sp_test

can anyone tell me what is wrong?

Comment: If you are counting list elements you can simplify: `select regexp_count('1,2,3,4', ',')+1 from dual;`.  Of course make sure the data does not contain the delimiter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing some quotes in dynamic SQL; this should work:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE SP_TBL_COMPARE_TEST3(
    SRC_COLS     IN VARCHAR2,
    TGT_COLS     IN VARCHAR2)
IS
  CNT1     NUMBER(5);
  SQL_TEXT2 VARCHAR(4000);

BEGIN
  SQL_TEXT2:= 'select count(*) from (select regexp_substr('''||src_cols||''','||'''[^,]+'||''', +1, level) from dual connect by regexp_substr('''||src_cols||''','||'''[^,]+'||''', +1, level) is not null )'; 
  dbms_output.put_line(SQL_TEXT2);
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SQL_TEXT2 into CNT1;
END;
```

Besides, notice that you never use the second parameter of your procedure.